# Unable to download process log file

Tags: web8, importexportservice

I'm writing a java client for the Import Export Service. It basically works fine: I'm able to export a package and download it as a zip file, upload that to another Tridion instance and import it.

The problem is with the 'unhappy flow'. If the package cannot be imported for some reason, all that the Import Export Service tells me is that the import has been aborted. When I try to download the log file (which is another nice feature of the IE Service), I get an error.

Here is my code:

```
File f = new File(packageName);
byte[] data;
data = getBytesFromFile(f);
final String packageId = iesu.uploadPackage(data);
final ImportInstruction instruction = new ImportInstruction();
final String processId = ies.startImport(packageId, instruction);
ProcessState state = ies.getProcessState(processId);
while (state != ProcessState.FINISHED && state != ProcessState.ABORTED) {
    state = ies.getProcessState(processId);
}
final ProcessInfo info = ies.getProcessInfo(processId);
final ProgressInfo pinfo = info.getProgressInfo().getValue();
if (state == ProcessState.ABORTED) {
    // THE NEXT LINE THROWS AN ERROR
    final byte[] logfile = iesd.downloadProcessLogFile(processId, false); 
    final String filename = processId + ".txt";
    final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    fos.write(logfile);
    fos.close();
    System.out.println("Import failed, see log file " + filename);
    throw new CoreServiceException("Import was aborted");
}
```

The call to downloadProgressLogFile always returns the same error:

> nl.robeco.tridionscript.tridion.CoreServiceException:
>   org.tempuri.IImportExportStreamDownloadDownloadProcessLogFileImportExportServiceFaultFaultFaultMessage:
>   Process log file associated with the process
>   62344fe7fdfa436d91be20bed2d25ccd does not exist.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have iesd.downloadProcessLogFile but is iesd defined? I assume it's not that simple...

Comment: I left out the assignment of the various web client variables for the sake of brevity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to enable process logging in the `ImportInstruction`.

Comment: perhaps. we're on 2013 SP1. we aren't setting anything explicitly on ImportInstruction for logging, but Web 8 could be different

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick:
   final ImportInstruction instruction = new ImportInstruction();
   instruction.setLogLevel(LogLevel.DEBUG);

Answer (score 1):

in downloadProcessLogFile, we pass in "true" not "false." can you try that?